# Add image or photo in the background of .3gp file

Tags: java, android, ffmpeg, javacv

I have an android app that records audio in 3gp format. Audio is recorded successfully and the file created.

I would add at least an image file to 3gp created but without using external libraries like ffmpeg, javacv as they leave the app created over 10MB in size.

Basically what I would like is information and sources about what search to add images to the background of my files 3gp audio libraries created without weighing the size of my apps.

Thank you